# TextMining of Twitter DB in RapidMiner evaluates all comments in a only way

Tags: twitter, svm, text-mining, rapidminer

I'm trying to use SVMs in RapidMiner to classify tweets contained in a database (TASS 2014 corpus), however, regardless of what that says Performance module, the applied model ends always evaluating all tweets in one way (ie all positive, all negative, all neutral, or all none). Not sure if I'm taking a misconfiguration.

[After Multipliy operator](http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140711042146793099.png), roles outputs are (first roles, second name, third type):

- text, text, text
- label, value, nominal
- id, tweetid, nominal

[After September Operator Role (2)](http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140711042147212040.png), roles outputs are (roles first, second name, third type):

- label, text, text
- id, tweetid, nominal

Then, I add the XML code of RapidMiner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.015">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="false" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Database" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="connection" value="sqlserver2014"/>
        <parameter key="query" value="SELECT TOP 4246 &quot;content&quot;, &quot;tweetid&quot;, &quot;value&quot;&#10;FROM &quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;TweetsTrainClean&quot;&#10;WHERE 'POS'=SUBSTRING(value,1,3)&#10;UNION ALL&#10;SELECT TOP 4246 &quot;content&quot;, &quot;tweetid&quot;, &quot;value&quot;&#10;FROM &quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;TweetsTrainClean&quot;&#10;WHERE 'NEU'=SUBSTRING(value,1,3)&#10;UNION ALL&#10;SELECT TOP 4246 &quot;content&quot;, &quot;tweetid&quot;, &quot;value&quot;&#10;FROM &quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;TweetsTrainClean&quot;&#10;WHERE 'NEG'=SUBSTRING(value,1,3)"/>
        <enumeration key="parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Database (5)" width="90" x="45" y="300">
        <parameter key="connection" value="sqlserver2014"/>
        <parameter key="query" value="SELECT top 1000 *&#10;FROM &quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;TweetsGeneralClean&quot;"/>
        <enumeration key="parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="false" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Database (2)" width="90" x="45" y="210">
        <parameter key="connection" value="sqlserver2014"/>
        <parameter key="query" value="SELECT *&#10;FROM (&#10;     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tweetid) AS RowNum&#10;     FROM &quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;TweetsGeneralClean&quot;&#10;     ) AS tabla&#10;WHERE tabla.RowNum BETWEEN 30000 AND 64798"/>
        <enumeration key="parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes (2)" width="90" x="179" y="255">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="|tweetid|content"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Process Documents from Data (2)" width="90" x="313" y="255">
        <parameter key="keep_text" value="true"/>
        <list key="specify_weights"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <connect from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Set Role (2)" width="90" x="447" y="255">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="text"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="label"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles">
          <parameter key="tweetid" value="id"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Database (3)" width="90" x="45" y="75">
        <parameter key="connection" value="sqlserver2014"/>
        <parameter key="query" value="select &quot;content&quot;,&quot;tweetid&quot;,&quot;value&quot; from &quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;TweetsTrainClean&quot;&#10;where 'POS'=SUBSTRING(&quot;value&quot;,1,3) or 'NEG'=SUBSTRING(&quot;value&quot;,1,3)&#10;&#9;or 'NEU'=SUBSTRING(&quot;value&quot;,1,3) or 'NON'=SUBSTRING(&quot;value&quot;,1,3)&#10;order by rand()"/>
        <enumeration key="parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text_to_nominal" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Text to Nominal" width="90" x="112" y="120">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="value"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="|type|value"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Set Role" width="90" x="179" y="30">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="tweetid"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="id"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles">
          <parameter key="value" value="label"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_text" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Nominal to Text" width="90" x="246" y="120">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="content"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Process Documents from Data" width="90" x="313" y="30">
        <parameter key="keep_text" value="true"/>
        <list key="specify_weights"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <connect from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="94" name="Multiply" width="90" x="380" y="120"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="x_validation" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation" width="90" x="514" y="30">
        <parameter key="number_of_validations" value="5"/>
        <parameter key="sampling_type" value="linear sampling"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="no_missing_values"/>
            <parameter key="attribute" value="content"/>
            <parameter key="attributes" value="tweetid|type||content"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_binominal" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="94" name="Nominal to Binominal" width="90" x="45" y="120">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
            <parameter key="attribute" value="value"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="polynomial_by_binomial_classification" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Polynominal by Binominal Classification" width="90" x="45" y="255">
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="support_vector_machine_linear" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="SVM (Linear)" width="90" x="45" y="255"/>
              <connect from_port="training set" to_op="SVM (Linear)" to_port="training set"/>
              <connect from_op="SVM (Linear)" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_training set" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="training" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Binominal" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Nominal to Binominal" from_port="example set output" to_op="Polynominal by Binominal Classification" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="Polynominal by Binominal Classification" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <list key="application_parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance" width="90" x="179" y="30"/>
          <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance" to_port="labelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Performance" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model (2)" width="90" x="648" y="210">
        <list key="application_parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read Database (5)" from_port="output" to_op="Select Attributes (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Process Documents from Data (2)" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data (2)" from_port="example set" to_op="Set Role (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Apply Model (2)" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
      <connect from_op="Read Database (3)" from_port="output" to_op="Text to Nominal" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Text to Nominal" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Text" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Nominal to Text" from_port="example set output" to_op="Process Documents from Data" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data" from_port="example set" to_op="Multiply" to_port="input"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 1" to_op="Validation" to_port="training"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 2" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Validation" from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model (2)" to_port="model"/>
      <connect from_op="Validation" from_port="averagable 1" to_port="result 3"/>
      <connect from_op="Apply Model (2)" from_port="labelled data" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 4" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to the data so I can't be sure for certain but I assume one of the attributes contains the complete tweet text as a few words.

With that assumption, the `Process Documents` operator needs to contain operators to split the text into tokens. Use the `Tokenize` operator for this and simply place it inside each of the `Process Documents` operators.

In addition, the word list output generated by the `Process Documents` for the training operation should be connected to the `Process Documents` operator which builds the test set. This is important as it eliminates any additional attributes from appearing in the test set that correspond to words that have not been seen during the training and therefore ensures the model will be applied correctly.